# How to run a certain blockchain project

Tags: javascript, deployment, blockchain, solidity

I'm new to blockchain and I want to know how to run a certain blockchain project. This is its GitHub repository.https://github.com/virajchandra51/MediVault. I have been trying to get it to run. How can I run this?

Currently, I'm getting this error.[This is the error I'm getting. I have changed the address in contact.json but doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z98D.jpg). Also, I'm getting the following warning when deploying the contract using node deploy.js.

```
node:51500) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
0xd09eD97239e278d591f80Eb45437895aa201F451
```

I have connected ganache to metamask using import accounts.

Comment: who are you quoting in your first paragraph? The deprecation warning is NOT the problem - it's a warning and won't stop correctly written code from running

Comment: Please update your question and post a minimal reproducible example of a code that's producing an error, see more tips in [tour]... Also note that: 1) `backend/crud.js` and `backend/deploy.js` in the linked code contain hardcoded paths, and it's likely that your local machine doesn't have these specific files in these specific paths. 2) There's a scam scheme among blockchain projects where someone asks you to run code from their whole repo in order to troubleshoot an alleged error, but the code tries to extract private keys from your machine. Be careful with running unchecked code.

Comment: Yes I have changed the path to a path in my local machine.